# actions in django

Tags: django, django-admin

How can i enable or disable actions according to the value of a field.For example In my model I have a status field which can have either of the value 'activate','pending','expired'.I am making a action which set the status equals to 'activate'.Know I want the action to be enable only if status is 'pending'.

Comment: Great question! My answer: Yes!

Answer (score 1):

This is some combination of the **Strategy** and **State** design patterns.

You'll be defining method functions for the action, and you'll want that method function to be sensitive to the state of your model instance.

Here's what we do.

```
class SpecialProcessing( object ):
    def __init__( self, aModelObject ):
        self.modelObject= aModelObject
    def someMethod( self ):
        pass

class SpecialProcessingActivate( SpecialProcessing ):
    def someMethod( self ):
        # do work if possible or raise exception of not possible

class SpecialProcessingPending( SpecialProcessing ):
    def someMethod( self ):
        # do work if possible or raise exception of not possible

class SpecialProcessingExpired( SpecialProcessing ):
    def someMethod( self ):
        # do work if possible or raise exception of not possible

class MyObject( models.Model ):
    status = models.CharField( max_length = 1 )
    def setState( self ):
        if self.status == "a":
            self.state = SpecialProcessingActivate(self)
        elif self.status == "p":
            self.state = SpecialProcessingPending(self)
        elif self.status == "x":
            self.state = SpecialProcessingExpired(self)
        else:
            raise Exception( "Ouch!" )
    def doSomething( self ):
        self.setState()
        self.state.someMethod()
```

This way, we can add new states (and state transition rules) freely without disturbing the model class too much.

Comment: This would evaluate the queryset, causing 1 query or action per row. If you use a filter you would remove the uneeded objects and allow you to modify the entire queryset with one swing.

Comment: Depends on when and how the change occurs.  In many instances the state change is A Big Deal, and the row-by-row query evaluation here is central to what's going on and this query is the heart of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Admin action methods provide you a queryset. Just slap an exclude or filter for pending

Answer (score -1):

i think using queryset is good approach